# How to go previous page in flutter while clicking mobile phone back button

Tags: dart, flutter

I am having fours pages with no tab bars If I want to click mobile phone back button to go the previous page. I didn't any solution to do it.

Comment: You should check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766382/flutter-change-back-button-from-navigation-bar).

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `Scaffold` with `WillPopScop`, `onWillPop` property will help you controll it as you like.

```
 return new WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: (){
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));

  },
  child : Scaffold( child : Center(child : Text('welcome to page 2 press back button to return to page 1 ') ),);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think flutter mange default when user press back button remove screen.then you can try this..

```
                    Navigator.pop(context);
```

more information refer this link..
https://medium.com/flutterpub/my-flutter-path-003-navigator-ad1472ff4e1a